# NLP- Finding the number of sentences which contain named entities

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am a beginner in NLP Python. I got a challenge to find the number of sentences that contain named entities. But I got a different answer by using two different methods. The first method I did it myself and the second one did by my instructor. I don't know what is wrong with my solution or **did I do something stupid!** Can anyone help me by explaining why I am getting two different answers?

By using this(First) method I got `34` as answer.

```
list_of_ners=[nlp(sent.text) for sent in doc.sents if sent.ents]
print(len(list_of_ners))//34
```

By using this(Second) method I got `36` as answer.

```
list_of_sents=[nlp(sent.text) for sent in doc.sents]
list_of_ners=[doc for doc in list_of_sents if doc.ents]
print(len(list_of_ners))//36
```